# Getting values from config in a component in Yii2

Tags: yii2

How can I access config values for a component in the component?

*config/main.php*

```
return [
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
        'mycomponent' => [
            'class' => 'common\components\MyComponent',
            'myConfigValue' => 'someValue',
        ],
        ...
```

How can i access `someValue` in the component?

I've tried to just declare the variable `public $someValue` in the class, but its not auto-populated.

Edit:

Here is my component:

```
namespace common\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

class myComponent extends Component
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public $someValue;

    public function getSomeValue()
    {
        return $someValue
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, use params for bublic attributes

Comment: You can access only to the public properties of the component http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-component.html or you need to extend it and add yours properties and method. t

Comment: could you please add the code of `common\components\MyComponent` ?

Comment: sure.. its not much yet tho

Answer (score 0):

According to [this guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/concept-components.md), you can override the `__construct()` method when creating your own component.

You can then set the property values as follows:

```
public function __construct($config = [])
{
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

Also in your method `getSomeValue()` you need to return `$this->someValue` instead of `$someValue`

Comment: @Jørgen did it work out for you? If so, please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact you're almost there... this question led me to an answer.

The key => values defined in your component (i.e. 'myConfigValue' => 'someValue') 
will be mapped to attributes of your component class. 
Note, keys that don't hae an attribute to b mapped to will throw an error.

```
class () ...

public $version = null;

public function __construct($config = [])
{
    // ... initialization before configuration is applied
    $this->config = $config;
    // use reflection
    // will map $config keys to attributes
    // e.g. 'version' => 1      mapped to $this->version
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```